# Rails: Pagination in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of products. When User click on product a modal appear with all the buy offers. How can I paginate this buy offers result into the modal?
Final goal is to implement infinite scroll in the modal (Like Twitter).

Relationships:

1. `Order has_many :buy_orders`
2. `BuyOrder belongs_to :product`

Products.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<button type="button" class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_<%= product.id %>">
Show Product
</button>
<% end %>

 <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal_<%= product.id %>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-left">BuyOffer</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

          <% product.buy_offers.each do |buyoffer| %>
            <%= buyoffer.total %>
          <% end %>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem  to achieve this

```
<% product.buy_offers.each do |buyoffer| %>
     <%= buyoffer.total %>
 <% end %>
```

replace above code with

```
   <% buyoffers = product.buy_offers.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10) %>
      <% buyoffers.each do |buyoffer| %>
        <%= buyoffer.total %>
      <% end %>
   <%= will_paginate buyoffers %>
```